# i found this error 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django

This is my code:

```py
similarity_score = []
for sentence1 in text:
    for sentence2 in text:
        if sentence1!=sentence2:
            sim_score = []
            temp2 = []
            sim = [[wn.word_similarity(word1,word2,'jcn') for word1 in sentence1] for word2 in sentence2]
            # s_sim = sum([sum(i) for i in zip(*sim)])
            s_sim = sum(sum_similarity(sim))
            sim_score.append(s_sim)
            # C_sim = content_sim(sentence1,sentence2)
            # sim_score.append(C_sim)
            # t_sim = sum([e/max(sim_score) for e in sim_score])
            t_sim = sum(sim_score)/len(sim_score)
            temp2.append(sentence1)
            temp2.extend((sentence2,t_sim))
            similarity_score.append(temp2)
return similarity_score
```

I am getting the following error:

> File "C:\Users\Waqar
>   Ahmad\projects\website\website\pages\Sentence_similarity.py", line 83,
>   in similarity
>       s_sim = sum(sum_similarity(sim)) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable [12/Sep/2019 22:02:51] "POST
>   /genericbased_similaritymatrix HTTP/1.1" 500 371830

Comment: where is `sum_similarity` defined?

Comment: Not much we can do to help until you show us what `sum_similarity` does...

Comment: did you use `return` in `sum_similarity` to return result ? if not then it returns `None` as default which means `NoneType`.

Comment: def sum_similarity(value_list):
    larger_lst = []
    for lst in value_list:
        values = []
        for e in lst:
            if max(lst) !=0:
                value = e/max(lst)
                values.append(value)
            else:values.append(0)
        larger_lst.append(sum(values))
   
    if max(larger_lst) != 0:
        return [e/max(larger_lst) for e in larger_lst]
        
    else:
        return larger_lst

Comment: One of sentence1 or sentence2 is coming as None. Inspect your text array or print these two variables for debugging.